# When were both minuscule and majuscule letters used for the first time in the same Latin manuscript?

Tags: roman-empire, language, latin-language

I understand the first minuscule script appeared in the Latin alphabet in the 3rd century - "New Roman cursive".

My question is: when did a script used both minuscule and majuscule letters in the same text, for the first time?

Comment: I assume this is for Latin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say [Half-Uncial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncial_script#Half-uncial) (3rd Century AD) and [Carolingian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolingian_minuscule) (9th Century AD) scripts; as it says in the Wikipedia text for the latter,

> Clear capital letters and spaces between words – norms we take for
>   granted – became standard in Carolingian minuscule [...]

So it was the first time both capitals and minuscules were used in a standard way (instead of ocassionally as with previous minuscule scripts). I don't think it would be possible to pinpoint exactly which was the first text ever to use them together, though.